# Asmx request - how to get all POSTed params

Tags: asp.net, asmx

is there a way to get all params that were posted to ASMX in ASP.NET . Request.Form/QueryString/Params - all do not contain keys that were submitted to the page.

Comment: Unless you are stuck on .NET 2.0, you shouldn't be using ASMX for new development. You should be using WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your ASMX gets invokes as HTTP POST with content type as "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`", you will not get those parameters from `HttpRequest` object.

This is simply because request body can be of any content type - for example, in script services (ASP.NET AJAX), the request body will have JSON data. If ASMX has been accessed as a SOAP web service then the request body will be an xml (the actual SOAP envelope).

Typically, ASP.NET run-time based on the configuration, attempts to parse the request body and tries to convert it into an method call along with actual method parameters. So the correct way would be to check your method parameters in the method code. A convoluted approach would be to refer request content type and parse (by your self) the request body (`HttpRequest.InputStream`) accordingly.

Comment: Thx. I'll use something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407902/set-global-variable-for-duration-of-a-request to store called service method params in some kind of Registry.